# multidimension arraylist c#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I want to create a multi-dimension `ArrayList` - I don't know the size, it should be decided at runtime.

how will I do that and how to access it?

It will be array of integers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the application for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
List<List<Integer>>
```

List by itself isn't multidimensional -- but you can use it to store Lists, which can then store Integers, in effect acting as a multidimensional array. You can then access elements as:

```
// Get the element at index x,y
int element = list[x][y];
```

To populate the list with initial elements, with dimensions x and y:

```
for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    // Have to create the inner list for each index, or it'll be null
    list.Add(new List<Integer>());

    for (int j=0; j<y; j++)
    {
        list[i].Add(someValue); // where someValue is whatever starting value you want
    }
}
```

Comment: how to access certain element add or display

Comment: I gave an example for accessing... I'll add an example for adding an element.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please leave a comment to let me know why.

Comment: List<List<int>> matrix = new List<List<int>>();

            // Intialize the inner lists 
            for (int j = 0; j < number; j++)
            {
                matrix[j] = new List<int>();
            
            
            } Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index could u help me in that

Comment: I downvoted because your first answer was to use ArrayList<> , something that doesn't exists. Also, to add an element to a List, you must use list[i].Add(somevalue)

Comment: There.. AMH described what happens when you don't use add =)

Comment: thanks alot , but how to access the inner list u said list[i].add() , what if as in matrix want to access element 0,0 or 1,2  , I mean insert in the position 0,0 or 0,1

Comment: You have to populate the whole two-dimensional thing first using Add in a loop. Once you have done that you can access elements using list[x][y] (as above), or set them using list[x].Insert(y, value)

Answer (score 2):

An ArrayList is not generic, hence you cannot specify what it will contain.
I would suggest using a regular generic List:

```
List<List<int>>
```

And for the accessing, just reference it by indices:

```
List<List<int>> myList = new List<List<int>>();
int item = myList[1][2];
```

Comment: List<List<int>> matrix = new List<List<int>>(); // Intialize the inner lists for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) { matrix[j] = new List<int>(); } Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index could u help me in that

Comment: Replace you `matrix[j] = new List<int>()` with `matrix.Add(new List<int>())` and you should be all good.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of potentially jagged lists you could also use a 2D array created with the [Array.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance.aspx) method if it never needs to change size after its created.

```
int[,] arrayOfInts = (int[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 4, 5);

arrayOfInts[0,0] = 5;
Console.WriteLine(arrayOfInts[0,0]);

arrayOfInts[0,4] = 3;
Console.WriteLine(arrayOfInts[0,4]);
```